# minecraft-server tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed a suggested edit that added [hosting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting) to a question with [minecraft-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-server).  Since Minecraft has been rather extremely updated in this regard, I think it warrants a meta discussion.  I'm not hugely up-to-date on current Minecraft, so if anything is incorrect feel free to fix it.

In ye olden days, when Minecraft was PC-only, there was a separate application used as a server.  This is still true, but I believe it is only for the java edition.  See [here](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/)

Now that most versions use the [bedrock edition](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Bedrock_Edition), the server functionality it built in to the game.  Combined with additional confusion with the introduction of [Realms](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360034670172-Minecraft-Realms-FAQs), tagging questions about hosting Minecraft servers might need clarification.

The [hosting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting) snippet reads:

> If your question is about a specific game's dedicated server software, please use the tag for that game's software instead

and the wiki states:

> If your question is about a specific game's dedicated server, please use the tag for that game instead, For example, use [minecraft-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-server) for Minecraft dedicated server questions.

Since Minecraft, for most users, no longer has a dedicated software for hosting, should we start using the [hosting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting) tag for non-java versions, or continue with the [minecraft-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-server) tag for everything?

Comment: Is minecraft hosting really no longer a thing? I'm still new to mc, but I see a lot of services for mc servers, so this kind of confuses me.

Comment: @shadi Looks like there is an alpha for server software for bedrock minecraft [here](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/bedrock/).  How that is different than the built-in server functionality, I'm not sure.

Comment: I feel minecraft-server and hosting are 2 separate things that can coexist. "hosting" would be OS-level whereas "minecraft-server" would be just config-level or the server software itself

Comment: @shadi that's fine, I just wanted to ask since some server-type Minecraft questions will no longer apply to the minecraft-server tag.  I suppose a more general phrasing would be "if a game has built-in server functionality, should questions related to hosting use the hosting tag"